# Cannot report new bugs to Bugzilla via J2Bugzilla

Tags: java, api, exception, bugzilla, issue-tracking

I tried searching this topic but nothing seems to cover my exact problem. I have a java and jsp program where I would like to be able to report bugs to my Bugzilla installation. I have been testing the method I created against the Bugzilla landfill first but I cant get it to work.

My problem is that I have tried all the sample code and I still end up with the same error which seems to stem from executeMethod().

Here is the sample of my jsp page which calls the method of my java class:

`<jsp:useBean id="error" class="bug.TestClass" scope="session"/>
<% String result = error.reportBug("error");
   out.print(result);%>`

The Java method, which I have blocked out the username and password to Bugzillla landfill but I have checked and they are correct:

```
    public static String reportBug(String bugError) { 
    try {
        BugzillaConnector conn = new BugzillaConnector();
        conn.connectTo("http://landfill.bugzilla.org/");
        BugzillaMethod logIn = new LogIn ("*****@hotmail.com", "****");
        conn.executeMethod(logIn);

        BugFactory factory = new BugFactory();
        Bug bug = factory.newBug()
        .setOperatingSystem("WINDOWS")
        .setPlatform("PC")
        .setPriority("P1")
        .setProduct("FoodReplicator")
        .setComponent("Salt")
        .setSummary(bugError)
        .setVersion("1.0")
        .setDescription("It doesn't work.")
        .createBug();

         ReportBug report = new ReportBug(bug);
         conn.executeMethod(report);
         int id = report.getID();

         result += "Successful";

    } catch (Exception e) {
       result = e.toString();
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here is the error I am getting when I open the jsp page:

```
com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaException: An unknown error was encountered; fault code: 0
```

I have been working on this for days so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue. Then I update j2bugzilla jar from 2.0 to 2.2.1. Then it works.